# How do scholars explain the Bible's seeming discrepancy over Morningstar/Daystar?

Tags: jesus, contradiction, historical-interpretation, latin-vulgate

> Revelation 22:16 I Jesus have sent my angel to testify to you these things in the churches. ***I am*** the root and the offspring of David, and ***the bright and morning-star***.
>   (WBS)

Jesus calls Himself the bright and morning star in Revelation 22:16,  what is the reasonable explanation for the seeming discrepancy in Holy Scripture the infallible Word of God, where it appears in the Latin Vulgate that the devil 'Lucifer' is also being called such in ***Isa 14:12-14:***

> King James Bible
>   12How art thou ***fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning***! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations!
>   13For **thou hast said in thine heart, I will ascend into heaven, I will exalt my throne above the stars of God: I will sit also upon the mount of the congregation, in the sides of the north:**
>   14
>   I will ascend above the heights of the clouds; ***I will be like the most High.***

It appears that the Bible calls both Jesus and the devil by 'morningstar' **How do scholars reasonably understand and explain this?**

Here is a link to a list of all the places the terms morningstar, daystar, Lucifer, etc. appear in scripture.

http://biblehub.com/concordance/m/morning-star.htm

Comment: Rev 22:16: ὁ ἀστὴρ ὁ λαμπρὸς ὁ πρωϊνός; Is. 14:12 (LXX): ὁ ἑωσφόρος ὁ πρωὶ ἀνατέλλων (Just a bit of supplemental info for those interested. The wording is very different. I’m not intending to criticize the question, though you’d be better off here avoiding assertions about biblical infallibility in questions I think. It's pretty clear that the author of Revelation was familiar with the text of Isaiah, so you don't really need to invoke infallibility to have a question.)

Comment: See also [this explanation regarding the referent of Isaiah 14:12](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/8068/3555).

Comment: I don't see why the same symbol couldn't be used to illustrate a good and a bad thing in different contexts - it actually happens in other parts of the Bible. For instance, wind is used as a symbol for the Holy-Spirit, but also to illustrate false doctrines... The thing is, these are resources to help visualize, not that the symbol actually is what it is illustrating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The morning star is the planet Venus, thought to be so beautiful that pagans associated it with the goddess Venus. It is natural that in Revelation 22:16 Jesus compares himself to the most admired star in the universe.

Scholars say that Isaiah chapter 14 refers to the king of Babylon, who laid the nations low ([Isaiah 14:12](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0839/__PNX.HTM)). Isaiah talks of the king's pomp and splendour, how he had ruled the nations in anger, and his fate after his overthrow by the king of Persia. He had compared himself to the Morning Star and was thus derisorily called 'Lucifer' (*lucem ferre*, which mean 'light-bearer', a name for the dawn appearance of the planet Venus) and had thought that he would ascend into heaven and sit among the stars, but was now himself persecuted (Isaiah 14:18-19). They say this text was misunderstood by early Christians, who assumed that it referred to Satan being cast down from heaven.

Comment: This clears it up, 'lucifer' latin, is actually a title, not a proper name, and came to be associated with Satan because the Isaiah passage, although speaking of the Babylonian king, seemed to also parallel passages about Satan in Eden, from Isaiah and other places, ie. Genesis, where Satan was in the garden of God and walked in the fire, himself covered with precious stones, he was called the 'annointed cherub', etc. meaning angel. Satan was an angel, a fallen one.

Answer (score 1):

How do you equate "son of the morning" to "bright morning star"? They are not the same thing. Actually, Lucifer in Isaiah 14:12 is more translatable to the word "Daystar," which he is called in at least four translations. Is a "day" star the same as a "morning" star? Look at 2 Peter 1:19 where Jesus is also the morning star. For me, it's a prophetic picture of new beginnings, new mercies and hope – the love of God; the Bride/the Church. Venus is a "wandering" star and is also called "The Shepherd's Star" because of this. Jesus calls himself the Good Shepherd and we are His sheep. He leaves the 99 to find the one lost sheep. Venus as the morning star represents Jesus
•   Revelation 22:16 – “I, Jesus, have sent My angel to testify to you these things in the churches. I am the Root and the Offspring of David, the Bright and Morning Star.”
•   2 Peter 1:19 – And so we have the prophetic word confirmed, which you do well to heed as a light that shines in a dark place, until the day dawns and the morning star rises in your hearts
A DAY STAR is one that seeks to be seen at praised at all times, even outshining the sun/Son. That's my perspective anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

King James Bible Isaiah 14:12

> How art thou fallen from heaven, O **Lucifer**, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations!

The term *Lucifer* is not found anywhere in the Hebrew scripture.

Young's Literal Translation

> How hast thou fallen from the heavens, O **shining one**, son of the dawn! Thou hast been cut down to earth, O weakener of nations.

O Morning Star,
הֵילֵ֣ל (hê·lêl)
Noun - masculine singular
Strong's 1966: The morning-star

Answer (score 0):

Peter also eludes to the arising of the "Day Star" in 2nd Peter 1
I have personally always interpreted this to be the light of the truth of Jesus Christ which can easily be seen not only within the darkness of the sin, But also shines so brightly that it can be easily seen even in the light of day as a visible testimony to us the believer.
Greg Stewart

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/44955)

Answer (score 0):

It was customary when a King deposed another King and his kingdom, that along with the kingdom, he acquired that king's title as well.

Therefore, if the King of Salem defeated the King of Loramar, he would be known as the King of Salem and Loramar.

Thus, when Satan as the Bright and MorningStar was defeated and cast down, Jesus acquired the title/name Satan had been known by.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).